# How can I hide the status bar in iOS 7.1?

Tags: ios, ipad, ios7, statusbar

In iOS 7.0, I hid the status bar in my apps by adding

```
<key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
<true/>
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
```

to the info.plist. I just updated my testing iPad to iOS 7.1, and the status bar is now back in all of my apps. How can I hide it in both 7.0 and 7.1?

Update: This is only happening in iPhone apps running on the iPad, I don't see this problem on the iPhone or in the simulator.

Comment: I submitted a bug report to Apple. If anyone finds a workaround before they fix this (assuming they do), please post it here.

Answer (score 1):

In the view controllers in which you want the status bar hidden, add the following method

```
- (BOOL)preferStatusBarHidden {
  return YES;
}
```

Then you can call

```
[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
```

which will fire the change to the status bar. This call can be done inside of an animation block which will animate the change.

Comment: I tried this in my main view controller but the status bar continues to appear.

Comment: Any solution to this? I'm seeing the same problem. I've tried all the "solutions" here and on the Apple Forums (not many there) and they do nothing. To make it worse the status bar appears ON TOP OF everything else so it effectively obscures whatever else you're putting at the top of the screen. I'm finally convinced it's a iOS bug, although I'm usually pretty slow to come to that conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following

```
   - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
        NSLog(@"View will appear");
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];

    }

    - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
    }
```

Comment: I tried adding them to my main view controller. Still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce the problem with a single-view iPhone-only app running in iPhone-compatibility mode in the simulator. But only when selecting an iPad non-retina on iOS 7.1.

My findings:

- The status bar will not be hidden, whatever you specified in the plist or in code.
- The problem doesn't occur on retina iPads
- The problem doesn't occur on iOS 7 or iOS 6

I tried these keys in the .plist:

```
<key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
<true/>
<key>UIStatusBarHidden~ipad</key>
<true/>
```

and

```
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance~ipad</key>
<false/>
```

I also tried the ViewController based-solution as mentioned by @Irfan to no avail.

There also seems no way to detect if the statusbar is shown as [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame returns {0, 0, 0, 0}

Comment: The only workaround I can come up with is to determine the device type using something like UIDeviceHardware (see https://gist.github.com/Jaybles/1323251) and then for non-retina iPads shift down your GUI to allow room for the status bar.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to ViewDidLoad:

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES
                                        withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
```

And Implement below Method:

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
return YES;
 }
```

It will hide status-bar of that particular ViewController in which you Implement it.
It works superbly good for me.
Hopefully it will also help you out.

Comment: Then I suggest you to make your app universal instead of running iphone App on ipad.

Comment: That worked for getting rid of the status bar, but messed up the UI. It would be possible to go through the apps and adjust and test all of the UI elements, but there's no way I could convince the customer that it would be worth it this late in the apps' lifecycle. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Ohhh that great that your problem is solved and you are able to convince your client :-) If you found my provided info little bit helpful in resolving and figure out your problem then kindly accept and up-vote my answer so it will may be helpful to others and it will be highly appreciated. Thanks cheers :-)

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I have found to this is to add the following:

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle) preferredStatusBarStyle {
    return -1;
}
```

wherever you have:

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return YES;
}
```

This is obviously terrible, but it seems to work for me -- at least so far.

UPDATE: I have noticed this causing output like the following:

```
<Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
```

I find another workaround, and it's possible that this error is what makes this workaround work, so I'm sticking with it, but it's worth noting.