# IOS 7 Statusbar showing when switching between apps

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios7, ios7-statusbar

I've run into something strange with an iPad app I'm currently working on. I have set the statusbar hidden with :

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden = YES;
```

in the AppDelegate.m

However when I switch between active apps on the device (iPad) by swiping with 4 vingers it's shows the statusbar for a couple of seconds before hiding it again. Is this inevitable/ is this the statusbar showing in the main OS and if not, how can I get it to stay hidden?

Cheers,

Nan

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18059703/cannot-hide-status-bar-in-ios7

Comment: Well the problem isn't that, it does hide while the app is active, but it is visible while I'm switching between apps on the ipad and disappears again when you're in the app for a couple of seconds

Comment: I understand. But did you add the above Boolean and test again?
And try adding     - (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
        return YES;
    } too.

Comment: I did add the above Boolean and adding the method also doesn't seem to work :\

Comment: My bad. It seems to be a common problem on the iPad. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22309834/how-can-i-hide-the-status-bar-in-ios-7-1